# How can I make my express app callback function wait before calling res.send, without using setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-firestore

I would like my callback function to wait until `ClientProductLinks` has been filled before sending it via res.send(). I'm sure there's a simple solution but I'm new to JS and cannot seem to figure it out.

```
app.all('/:client/listproducts', async function(req, res) {
   const client = req.params.client;
   let clientProductLinks = [];
   const clientRef = await db.collection(client).get();
   const snapshot1 = await clientRef;
   snapshot1.forEach(async function (prod) {
       let prodRef = await db.collection(client).doc(prod.id).collection(prod.id).get();
       let snapshot2 = await prodRef;
       snapshot2.forEach(function (doc) {
           const obj = {
               docID: doc.id,
               docData: doc.data()
           };
           clientProductLinks.push(obj);
       });
   });
   res.send(clientProductLinks);
});
```

Currently, res.send() sends `ClientProductLinks` back as an empty array. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way you are using await inside a foreach loop isn't working the way you expect.  You will need to collect the promises into an array and actually await all of them together.  This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: `Array.forEach` doesn't `await` it's callback. You need to either use a `for..of` loop or `Promise.all`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting synchronous execution (`snapshot1.forEach`) when really writing asynchronous code.

In this case you should be able to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all your product links.

Something like (untested):

```
app.all('/:client/listproducts', async function(req, res) {
  const client = req.params.client;
  const snapshot1 = await db.collection(client).get();
  const getProduct = async prod => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const snapshot2 = await db
          .collection(client)
          .doc(prod.id)
          .collection(prod.id)
          .get();
        const links = [];
        snapshot2.forEach(function(doc) {
          const obj = {
            docID: doc.id,
            docData: doc.data()
          };
          links.push(obj);
        });
        resolve(links);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };

  const clientProductLinks = await Promise.all(snapshot1.map(getProduct));
  res.send(clientProductLinks);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Running this yields ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: snapshot1.map is not a function```. I had this problem before; for some reason I am allowed to call forEach(), but not map(), on the snapshot arrays.

Comment: What is `db`? Mongo DB?

Comment: It's firestore actually